# Porque meus VirtualHosts apontam para a pasta root.?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Estou usando o **Apache 2** no **Ubuntu 14.04**. Movi a pasta `www/html` para minha outra partição `/media/Dados/www`. Mas não é este o problema.

O problema começa quando defini um vhost para um subdiretorio:

**Subdiretório:** `/media/Dados/www/ak-vitrine`

**Arquivo em sites-available:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ak-vitrine.dev
    ServerAlias www.ak-vitrine.dev

    DocumentRoot "/media/Dados/www/AK-Vitrine"

    <Directory "/media/Dados/www/AK-Vitrine">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Ao acessar http://ak-vitrine.dev ele me mostra a lista de pastas da pasta root `/media/Dados/www/`. Como resolver?

Comment: Como não sou especialista no assunto (e ainda estou engatinhando com Linux), experimenta: 1) Dar um nome pro VirtualHost: `<VirtualHost akvitrine.localhost:80>` 2) Remover as *Options*. Adicionalmente, caso venha a enfrentar alguns *Forbiddens* (como eu) adicione **Require all granted** dentro do `<Directtory>`. Ah! E lembre-se que ambientes *nix são *case-sensitive*, logo **ak-vitrine** é diferente de **AK-Vitrine**

Comment: Nem o apelido ao VirtualHost, nem remover as Options funcionou =/

Comment: Solução encontrada, postei a resposta :)
Obrigado pela ajuda Bruno, foi com ela que me veio a ideia.

Answer (score 1):

Eu mesmo cheguei a solução, após muita, muita pesquisa.
Primeiro usei o comando:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

Isso desabilita o virtualhost padrão do apache (geralmente o que vem escrito "Its Works")

Com isso bastava criar o virtualhost corretamente, prestando atenção para incluir a extensão .conf nos arquivos de sites-available e sites-enabled.
Para facilitar criei um bash para a criação sem erro (pelo menos no mesmo ambiente) do virtualhost.

Para isso use no terminal:

```
sudo gedit /usr/local/bin/addvhost
```

e cole o conteúdo de http://pastebin.com/pRWCLPc8

Depois basta executar no terminal `sudo addvhosts` para adicionar um vhost.
Ele irá perguntar qual o nome do projeto e qual o diretório, criando os arquivos necessários e restartando o apache.

Espero que esta informação seja útil para alguém. :)

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente o diretório está sem permissão, ou como o Bruno falou, deve ser problema de *case sensitive* no nome do teu diretório.

Comment: Sim, tenho em mente o case-sensitive. Verifiquei os locais e nomes, e esta tudo correto =/